# Grouping array nested value while comparing 2 objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working in small react project & I am facing issue in grouping the data. Requirement is to group the id & its feature into a single row if same id is there in before & after object.

Json Data:

```
{
"before":{
"device": [
{
  id:"1234",
  price:"10,
  features:[
   {name:"samsung",price:"10"},
   {name:"Apple",price:"20"}
  ]
},
   {id:"2154",
   price:"20, 
   features:[
    {name:"samsung",price:"30"},
    {name:"Moto",price:"40"}
   ]
]
},
"after":{
"device": [
{
 id:"1234",
 price:"50, 
 features:[
  {name:"samsung",price:"20"},
  {name:"Lenovo",price:"30"}
 ]
},
 {id:"2158",
  price:"40, 
 features:[
 {name:"samsung",price:"30"}
]
]
}
}
```

Expected grouping to be shown in UI is shared in image.

I tried to get unique ids in one array and lopping through after array and comparing unique array id I am getting unique id to show but issue i am facing while grouping their related feature.

Can anyone please help me to get a best approach to handle this requirement.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: In respect to show data you can simply  loop through your data, actually I didn't try react, but I can give solution in jquery may be it will help you:

$.each(res.devices, function(d)){ $.each(d.features, function(f){f.name+f.price})}

Comment: @WaseelAhmadMufti Why on earth use jQuery to process an array. Vanilla JS has map, reduce, forEach

Comment: @mplungjan yes you are right. I don't know why I mentioned Jquery, but he can use map, reduce, forEach functions, 
if we use vanilla Js with forEach, then code should be look like:
obj.devices.forEach(function(item, index)){ item.feature.forEach(function(feature_item, feature_index){feature_item.name+feature_item.price})}

Comment: Also please do not waste out time with invalid JSON. If we cannot trust your data, we cannot help you merge it

Comment: Is this the data you have when corrected? `{ "before": { "device": [{ "id": "1234", "price": "10", "features": [{ "name": "samsung", "price": "10" }, { "name": "Apple", "price": "20" } ] }, { "id": "2154", "price": "20", "features": [{ "name": "samsung", "price": "30" }, { "name": "Moto", "price": "40" } ] }], "after": { "device": [{ "id": "1234", "price": "50", "features": [{ "name": "samsung", "price": "20" }, { "name": "Lenovo", "price": "30" } ] }, { "id": "2158", "price": "40", "features": [{ "name": "samsung", "price": "30" }] }] } } }`

Comment: sorry for the inconvienence. Here is the formatted Json.
{ "before": { "device": [ { "id": "1234", "price": "10", "features": [ { "name": "samsung", "price": "10" }, { "name": "Apple", "price": "20" } ] }, { "id": "2154", "price": "20", "features": [ { "name": "samsung", "price": "30" }, { "name": "Moto", "price": "40" } ] } ] }, "after": { "device": [ { "id": "1234", "price": "50", "features": [ { "name": "samsung", "price": "20" }, { "name": "Lenovo", "price": "30" } ] }, { "id": "2158", "price": "40", "features": [{ "name": "samsung", "price": "30" }] } ] } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a nested approach for grouping.

```js
var data = { before: { device: [{ id: "1234", price: "10", features: [{ name: "samsung", price: "10" }, { name: "Apple", price: "20" }] }, { id: "2154", price: "20", features: [{ name: "samsung", price: "30" }, { name: "Moto", price: "40" }] }] }, after: { device: [{ id: "1234", price: "50", features: [{ name: "samsung", price: "20" }, { name: "Lenovo", price: "30" }] }, { id: "2158", price: "40", features: [{ name: "samsung", price: "30" }] }] } },
    cols = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(data).map(k => [k, 0])),
    result = Object.values(Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [col, { device }]) => {
        device.forEach(({ id, price, features }) => {
            r[id] = r[id] || [{ id, ...cols }];
            r[id][0][col] = price;
            features.forEach(({ name, price }) => {
                let temp = r[id].find(q => q.name === name);
                if (!temp) r[id].push(temp = { name, ...cols });
                temp[col] = price;
            });
        });
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things i'd suggest you:

1.) Please verify the data your'e posting is correct and in proper format, people won't be able to help if the data is incorrect.

2.) The UI display requirement should be simple enough.

Now, if you still want to achieve this requirement i believe the correct JSON and the merged output json will look something like below:

```
//Correct input data that you have:

    var input = {
      "before": {
        "device": [
          {
            "id": "1234",
            "price": "10",
            "features": [
              {
                "name": "samsung",
                "price": "10"
              },
              {
                "name": "Apple",
                "price": "20"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "2154",
            "price": "20",
            "features": [
              {
                "name": "samsung",
                "price": "30"
              },
              {
                "name": "Moto",
                "price": "40"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "after": {
        "device": [
          {
            "id": "1234",
            "price": "50",
            "features": [
              {
                "name": "samsung",
                "price": "20"
              },
              {
                "name": "Lenovo",
                "price": "30"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "2158",
            "price": "40",
            "features": [
              {
                "name": "samsung",
                "price": "30"
              }
            ]
    
          }
        ]
      }
    };

// Output JSON which you should need to show the desired output.

    var output = {
      "devices": [
        {
          "id": 1234,
          "feature": [
            {
              "name": "1234",
              "price": {
                "before": 10,
                "after": 50
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "samsung",
              "price": {
                "before": 10,
                "after": 20
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "apple",
              "price": {
                "before": 10,
                "after": 0
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "lenovo",
              "price": {
                "before": 0,
                "after": 30
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
```

3.) Please try to get the desired output from input yourself as this will help you learn a lot of things in between, as suggested by some please use map, filter, forEach for your requirement.

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lodash` library for grouping

https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#groupBy

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing 2 objects, and output equivalent values

```js
var has = {"before":[{
  name: 'Nokia',
  os: 'Andriod',
  features: {
    camera: "200 MPixel Camera",
    battery: "24 hours battery backup",
  }
}],
"after":[{
  name: 'Samsung',
  os: 'Andriod',
  features: {
    camera: "200 MPixel Camera",
    battery: "30 hours battery backup",
  }
}]
};




function compare(Pro1, Pro2) {
  var Val1 = Object.values(Pro1);
  var Val2 = Object.values(Pro2);
  var equivalent = [];

  var keys = Object.keys(Pro1);
  keys.forEach(k => {
    if (Pro1.hasOwnProperty(k) && Pro2.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      if (typeof Pro1[k] === 'object') {
        let recursiveResult = compare(Pro1[k], Pro2[k]);
        equivalent.push(...recursiveResult);
      } else if (Pro1[k] === Pro2[k]) {
        equivalent.push(Pro1[k]);
      }
    }
  });
  
  return equivalent;
}

let equiv = compare(has["before"], has["after"]);
console.log(equiv);
```